# Problems with Moarfonts after updating to XCode 6

Tags: xcode, plugins, fonts, xcode6, custom-font

I encountered a problem with **Moarfonts** ([site](http://pitaya.ch/moarfonts/)) after upgrading from XCode 5.1 to XCode 6.
The build phase of a project fails showing the following error:

> moarfonts[4477:507] *** Assertion failure in -[FontCache initWithSDKRootURL:], /Users/0xced/Projects/MoarFonts/moarfonts/FontCache.m:33
>   error: Font cache directory not found

I tried the troubleshooting from the author of that plugin (from the site of the plugin), but no luck!
Has anyone found and solved this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging up a little bit (nothing to do, unluckly), I've found this [link](http://ix.io/bEo) while looking for the hashtag **#moarfonts** on Twitter.
That link shows the content of a bash script, and inside that there is the following directory path:

> $SDKROOT/System/Library/.lilid/.lilic

With this link, I've looked for the value of SDKROOT (following example from troubleshooting guide from plugin's site), and it appears that it has to be equals to the location of iOS8 SDK.
Looking for that directory path (`$SDKROOT/System/Library/.lilid/.lilic`) gave no result. So I looked for it inside the previously used SDK directory (iOS 7.1 for me, from folder `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk`), and there I found the directory `System/Library/.lilid/.lilic`).
At that point, the solution was to copy the folder `.lilid` from the iOS 7.1 SDK folder to iOS 8 SDK folder (inside `System/Library`, i.e.: maintaining folder structure).
After that, I could build my project with no other problems.
Hope this helps.